# Define new code section in assembly code to compile ELF binary

Tags: assembly, c, elf, dynamic-linking

I defined a new code section in my assembly program, which is going to be compiled into 32-bit ELF binary, on x86.

I use the linker scripts to assign a specified address for this new code section, it works. However, I noticed that this new section does not be loaded to the memory, after some debugging!

I use `readelf` and figure out that there is no "execution" privilege of this new section:

```
[15] .trampoline       PROGBITS        080483d0 004020 000117 00      0   0 16
```

Then I did this:

```
objcopy --set-section-flags .trampoline=alloc,code a.out
```

However, I got this warning:

```
BFD: stQWykoH: warning: allocated section `.trampoline' not in segment
```

Now I realize that I didn't explicitly assign a `segment` information to my new section!!

So here is my question:

1. How to assign a `segment` information to a new code section I defined? I double-checked the linker script (follow instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508290/how-to-specify-base-addresses-for-sections-when-linking-or-alternatively-how-to/9550165#9550165) to dump), and I have no idea how to modify the script...
2. I just want to add a new executable section to my assembly program, and assign a fixed address to this new section. So am I on the right way now?